# realloc, for string array in C

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

Is there a correct way to use realloc, for when you want to add words of variable size to a string array? I am getting a segmentation fault.
Please show me what's wrong

```
// This function puts every word found in a text file, to a String array, **words
char **concordance(char *textfilename, int *nwords){
    FILE * fp;
    char *fileName = strdup(textfilename);
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }
    char **words = malloc(sizeof(char));
    // char **words = NULL

    char line[BUFSIZ];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL){
        char *word = strdup(line);
        word = strtok(word, " ");
        do{
            words = realloc(words, (*nwords+1) * sizeof(char(*)));
            words[*nwords] = word;
        } while((word = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL);
    }
    return words;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int *nwords = malloc(sizeof(int));
    nwords = 0;
    concordance("test.txt", nwords);
}
```

Comment: `char **words = malloc(sizeof(char));` looks fishy to me

Comment: Have you used a debugger (gdb or valgrind) to check your program?!

Comment: `char **words` should be allocated to size of pointer and to the maximum number of pointers you want to store, e.g. `char **words = malloc(sizeof(char *)*1000);` for a maximum of 1000 pointers.

Comment: Antonio. I tried this, still doesn't work

Comment: You really shouldn’t be using `strtok()` unless you really know what you’re doing, because it modifies the string you’re scanning replacing the delimiter with a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initiate the value of `nwords`, you   were overwriting its pointer address, not its value.

Additionally, as the commenter says, the line `char **words = malloc(sizeof(char));` is not correct. But you always re-allocate the variable `words` so the code still works as expected. To make it super safe you should change it to `char **words = malloc(sizeof(char*));`

I use the line `*nwords = 0;` and now it works as expected.

```
#define BUFSIZ 1000
#include<stdio.h>
// This function puts every word found in a text file, to a String array, **words
char **concordance(char *textfilename, int *nwords){
  FILE * fp;
  char *fileName = strdup(textfilename);
  fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
  if(fp == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
  }
  char **words = malloc(sizeof(char));
  // char **words = NULL

  char line[BUFSIZ];
  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL){
    char *word = strdup(line);
    word = strtok(word, " ");
    printf("word='%s'\n",word);
    do{
      *nwords=*nwords+1;
      printf("nwords=%d\n",*nwords);
      words = realloc(words, (*nwords+1) * sizeof(char(*)));
      words[*nwords] = word;
    } while((word = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL);
  }
  return words;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  int *nwords = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *nwords = 0;
  concordance("test.txt", nwords);
}
```

Comment: `char **words = malloc(sizeof(char));` can impossibly work as expected.

Comment: it  just gives a pointer to a singe byte. Then the code always reallocates it with the right amount of words anyway. It's not philosophically right, but works.

Comment: Never `realloc` with the pointer itself. If `realloc` fails (and it does) it returns `NULL` overwriting your address preventing the original block from ever being freed creating a memory leak. Use a temp pointer, e.g. `void *tmp = realloc (words, (nwords + 1) * sizeof *words);` then validate `tmp != NULL`. (and note reallocating by 1-pointer each iteration is horribly inefficient, better to allocate multiple pointers in blocks and keep track of the number used and `realloc` when you run out)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to initialize `nwords` to `0`, in a wrong way. As you have declared it as a pointer, you can not access it directly. instead, you should use the de-reference operator `*`.

make the following change in the `main` function

`*nwords = 0;` instead of `nwords = 0;`

`nwords = 0` modifies the location to which `nwords` is pointing to, to the location with address `0`, to which you have no access and can not assign.

**WARNING:**

1. It is better not to perform `realloc` on the same pointer, it will make the pointing location `NULL` if the `realloc` fails, leading to the loss of the previously existing data. Instead, as @David suggests, you could use a temp variable to `realloc` memory and then, check if it is not `NULL` and then assign its contents to the `words` pointer.

```c
    //your code
    char *tmp = realloc(words, /* new size*/);
    if(tmp != NULL)
        words = tmp;
    // your code
```

2. while using `realloc` you usually use it to allocate a block of data, not for a single location.

Comment: See comment under other answer about "Never realloc with the pointer itself....". Always good to point out potential errors.